# T-SQL Multi-Statement Table-Valued Function

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, user-defined-functions, table-valued-parameters

I could really use some help writing a multi-statement table-valued function that uses the following logic:

- Accepts a varchar parameter as input
- If the parameter starts with A, run a select statement
- If no rows are returned, run a select statement
- If the parameter does not start with A, run a select statement
- If no rows are returned, run a select statement
- Returns an output table, which will be one of the result-sets from above depending on the parameter

So far, this is what I have:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckAccess
(@UserName varchar(30))
RETURNS @AccessTable TABLE (User varchar(max), Access varchar(max))
AS

BEGIN
   IF LEFT(@UserName,1) = 'A'
       INSERT INTO @AccessTable
       SELECT
           CASE
           WHEN EXISTS (SELECT User, Access FROM dbo.AccessTable1 WHERE User = @UserName)
           THEN (SELECT User, Access FROM dbo.AccessTable1 WHERE User = @UserName)
           ELSE (SELECT @UserName User, 'No Access' Access)
           END
   ELSE
      INSERT INTO @AccessTable
      SELECT
           CASE
           WHEN EXISTS (SELECT User, Access FROM dbo.AccessTable2 WHERE User = @UserName)
           THEN (SELECT User, Access FROM dbo.AccessTable2 WHERE User = @UserName)
           ELSE (SELECT @UserName User, 'No Access' Access)
           END
RETURN
END;
```

Not sure what I'm missing here, but I'm receiving the errors below:

```
Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure CheckAccess, Line 90
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure CheckAccess, Line 92
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure CheckAccess, Line 11
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

I know how to do this fairly easily in a stored procedure, using temp tables, but since they are not an option in functions, I'm having a bit of difficulty.  If anyone can offer some suggestions, I'd really appreciate it.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your function using `@@rowcount` server variable as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckAccess
   (@UserName varchar(30))
   RETURNS @AccessTable TABLE (User varchar(max), Access varchar(max))
AS

BEGIN
   IF LEFT(@UserName,1) = 'A'
       INSERT INTO @AccessTable
        SELECT User, Access FROM dbo.AccessTable1 WHERE User = @UserName
   ELSE
      INSERT INTO @AccessTable
        SELECT User, Access FROM dbo.AccessTable2 WHERE User = @UserName

   --@@rowcount gives number of records inserted/affected from immediately previous query
   IF @@RowCount = 0 
      INSERT INTO @AccessTable
       SELECT @UserName User, 'No Access' Access

   RETURN

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of a boolean check like this

```
EXISTS (SELECT User, Access FROM dbo.AccessTable1 WHERE User = @UserName)
```

try

```
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.AccessTable1 WHERE User = @UserName)
```

generally an EXISTS expression does not need specific results, it just needs to check wether NULL is returned because no row could be found or wether something could be returned no matter what that is. It's a boolean expression that evaluates to yes or no. The '1' suffices for that purpose. The first two error messages are about that.

The next problem is that a CASE-expression by definition can only define one field and one field only. It can't return the needed two fields. Thats what the last error message is propably about, the function is defined as returning two fields. You could now write two CASE-expressions seperated by a comma.

I would suggest a different approach for Your logic though: within your IF-statment do sub-IFs, like nested IFs. I have not tested this, just an idea:

```
   IF LEFT(@UserName,1) = 'A'
     IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.AccessTable1 WHERE User = @UserName)
       INSERT INTO @AccessTable
       SELECT User, Access FROM dbo.AccessTable1 WHERE User = @UserName
     ELSE (SELECT @UserName User, 'No Access' Access)

   ELSE
     IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.AccessTable2 WHERE User = @UserName)
      INSERT INTO @AccessTable
      SELECT User, Access FROM dbo.AccessTable2 WHERE User = @UserName
     ELSE (SELECT @UserName User, 'No Access' Access)
```

or another idea that propably performs better but I am not sure whether this meets your requirement for the field 'Access' 100 percent. If @username is present in the table will ther *allways* be content in the Access-field?

```
   IF LEFT(@UserName,1) = 'A'
       SELECT 
         ISNULL(User,@UserName) User
         ,ISNULL(Access,'No Access') Access 
       FROM dbo.AccessTable1 WHERE User = @UserName
   ELSE
       SELECT 
         ISNULL(User,@UserName) User
         ,ISNULL(Access,'No Access') Access 
       FROM dbo.AccessTable2 WHERE User = @UserName
```

One additional remark: an IF (also ELSE) will only consider one following statement. Should there be more than one statement to be run you would need to encapsule them by BEGIN and END like so

```
IF @fact=1
  BEGIN
    statement 1
    .
    .
    statement n
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    statement 1
    .
    .
    statement n
  END
```